# Loading AMD modules on demand with own require config

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have a shell app that has a require.config specifying some dependencies/shims etc.

The shell can load packages that contain submodules which require thier own require.config, but I cannot tell what modules will be loaded or when.

I need to load the require.config for a specific package when any of the submodules are loaded.

ie:

```
Shell
Shell.config
--->Package1
--->Package1-config
------>Module1
------>Module2
```

The shell could open either Module1 or Module2 and I want the config to be loaded to specify the module paths/shims,etc

I seem to be able to do it by adding the require.config above my module definition, but then I have to include it in each module.

Is there a way I can get it so it loads the package config once and then subsequent modules do not need to load it again?

Thanks

Comment: I should possibly mention that the packages are not subfolders of the shell app. They are self-contained components that are loaded by the shell within the same domain and can be reused by different applications (which is why they need their own library paths).
It would also be good if they could inherit any libs already loaded by the shell so they are not reloaded